# How to nest conditional statements in react - getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently getting my favourites `state` as undefined. The `state` is empty upon loading. How do I nest another conditional statement to get my conditional statement to work correctly?

Failed attempt:

```
  {favourites !== null &&
          favourites.find((fav: IEpisode) => fav.id === episode.id)
            ? "Unfav"
            : "Fav"}
```

Undefined code:

```
const initialState: IState = {
  episodes: [],
  favourites: [],
};

  {favourites.find((fav: IEpisode) => fav.id === episode.id)
            ? "Unfav"
            : "Fav"}
```

Comment: There's not enough context here to understand why anything would be undefined. *If* you're setting your initial state to an empty array, *and* you're correctly accessing that state, *and* you're checking for an empty array (if that's what you care about), having a strict check for `null` doesn't make a lot of sense since `null` is neither `undefined` nor an empty array.

Comment: I was just trying to toggle a button from "Fav" to "Unfav" when the favourites is being put in/out the array. I just get favourites is undefined and my app wont run. Sorry i'm not very good at asking questions on here. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to nest conditionals; but it reduces readability, better extract it to a function; this is how to do with ternary statements

```
  <div>{favourites ?
      (favourites.find((fav: IEpisode) => fav.id === episode.id)
        ? "Unfav"
        : "Fav") : "Some other placeholder or empty string" }</div>
```